# how to prefix a culture string such as "en-gb" before the {controller} position in the url in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multilingual, currentculture

so basically I want to achieve a multi-lingual website with the following scenarios:

- Using ASP.NET MVC 3
- most language are using resource files so they are using same views, however there are also many views that are country-specific (i.e. language culture specific) and not available for all.
- **example url:   http://localhost/en-us/{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}**

The MVC folder structure as here:

```
- Areas
    - Channel1
        - Controllers
        - Content
        - Views
            - en-us
                - View1.cshtml
                - View2.cshtml
            - zh-cn
                - View1.cshtml
                - View2.cshtml
                <b>- Special.cshtml</b>

    - Channel2
       ....(similar folder structure)
- ....
```

I think there must be a way to define the  "en-us" into a parameter like {lang} and make decision in a default Controller outside the Areas - however I'm asp.net MVC newbie, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always write your own viewengine to look at folders based on what comes in.  There's code out there for a [ThemedViewengine that does just that](http://cgeers.com/2010/02/25/asp-net-mvc-themed-view-engine/).

Comment: thx, I made some changes based on that code and now works nicely!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fantastic article with practical suggestions on how to implement globalization on ASP.NET MVC 3

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

Comment: I need to figure out the url bit - detecting culture via the url and render the view accordingly

Answer (score 0):

There's no great way to do this, but it is possible.  First, you need to rearrange your views a little bit -- they still have to have a controller.  Let's say the files you have (`View1.cshtml` and `View2.cshtml`) live in your home controller.  Put them here:

```
- Views
  - Home
    - en-us
      - View1.cshtml
      - View2.cshtml
    - zh-cn
      - View1.cshtml
      - View2.cshtml
```

Then, create a custom route for the views in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MultiLingual",
    "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new {  controller = "Home", action = "Index", lang="en-us", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Finally, in your home controller (or whatever controller you want to put the views in), use the `lang` parameter to determine which view to use:

```
public ActionResult View1( string lang, int? id ) {
    return View( lang + "/View1" );
}

public ActionResult View2( string lang, int? id ) {
    return View( lang + "/View2" );
}
```

I tried this and it works, but it feels awfully clunky, and not very DRY (at least in the actions).  Anyone have a better approach?

Comment: you are right - that means you have to handle "lang" variable for every single view and controller - which obviously isn't the ideal solution... I'm trying to figure out a way to do it...